# How to switch user when `sudo bash` script with only one login user?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

My system is debian 10,has only one login user `boy` with `sudo` privilege.

```
##!/bin/bash
##root cannot log in
set -e
#expect root
whoami
user='boy'
su $user
#expect 'boy',but not
whoami
su - root
#expect root,but not
whoami
```

When I `sudo bash ./***.sh` to run above bash script,expect output is:

```
root
boy
root
```

How to switch user when `sudo bash` script with only one login user?

Comment: `whoami` doesn't happen until `su - root` has finished running and exits (meaning you're no longer root anymore).

Comment: Similarly, the other `whoami` doesn't run until after `su $user` exits.

Comment: Either use the `-c` argument to `su`, or pass code to be run under the shell `su` starts in a heredoc. The linked duplicate has answers describing both techniques.